# how to understand whether there des not exist such cookie with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, cookies

How to check whether a cookie named, let's say *username* exist?

I have to code Javascript code that will run when that cookie is not set.

Comment: Can you use jQuery? It's makes this action trivial `$.cookie('name') == null`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should help you get started:

```
function checkCookie(){
var username=getCookie("username");
  if (username!=null && username!="")
  {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}


function getCookie(c_name){
var i,x,y,ARRcookies=document.cookie.split(";");
for (i=0;i<ARRcookies.length;i++)
{
  x=ARRcookies[i].substr(0,ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
  y=ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=")+1);
  x=x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
  if (x==c_name)
    {
    return unescape(y);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

- http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp
- http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html
- http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaScript/Development/Cookiesetdeletegetvalueandcreate.htm
- http://www.brenz.net/cookies/get_cookie.asp

And finally an example: http://jsfiddle.net/hZ3Xn/